# Using C++/WinRT on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c++, com, dllregistration

I am working on a new COM+ plugin for use on Windows.  We are trying to use C++/WinRT because of being orders of magnitude cleaner and easier to use than ATL and C APIs.  The problem is that since we are not using the runtime broker to expose the DLL methods we need to supply a `DllMain`, `DllCanUnloadNow` `DllGetClassObject`, `DllRegisterServer`, and `DllUnregisterServer`.  The MS documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-coclasses on the subject, but they do not cover what needs to be done with `DllRegisterServer` and `DllUnregisterServer`.  Are these the same implementations as a normal COM DLL where you just set the registry values?  I am very naive when it comes to actually implementing COM plugins, so I am not familiar with how these methods are implemented usually.

Comment: Perhaps this may be affecting. COM+ System Application StartType=Manual [Guidance on disabling system services on Windows Server 2016 with Desktop Experience](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/blob/master/WindowsServerDocs/security/windows-services/security-guidelines-for-disabling-system-services-in-windows-server.md)

Comment: I added registry entries for the CLSID manually for `InprocServer32` and `ProdId` so it seems to load the object, but it seems to crash in a dereference in `winrt::implements<...>::Release` so something might be missing from the actual interface still.